# What is this anime about a church orphan who had to testify against his fat friend?

Tags: blassreiter

I'm looking for an anime I watched on TV. I don't remember any character names, but just the story, which went something like this:

> In the anime, a team of soldiers were running to a helicopter to get away from the infected robot-like creatures. They got into the lift, however, when they were about to leave, one of the guys got bitten and slowly turned into one of the infected creatures. He told the others to leave him behind, then he shot himself in the head before the transformation complete. The others continues on their escape, and more of the robot-like creatures came after them. Two more guys got taken out, and only a girl and a guy remained.
>
> Later, an enemy showed up, who was someone they knew. He could control the
>   virus, and it gave him superpowers by transforming his body's surface into a mechanical suit. He was getting orders from a woman, who probably was wearing a lab coat. The guy sacrificed himself and somehow saved the girl.
>
> The girl ended up in a very big facility that wanted to destroy both the infected robot-like creatures and the humans who could control the virus' power. The girl knew how to drive, so she was assigned as a driver to a team. She was in the place where they kept the customized tanks and/or big vehicles. She did not know that the guy in her team who saved her was still alive and was held prisoner in the same facility somewhere. He was unconscious. When he woke up, he had lost his memories, and he also became like the infected robot-like humans. He had a headache, and he wandered in the facility trying to find an exit.
>
> As the guards chased him, he found a room in which there was a bike protected by a barrier, and there was a control panel. When he touched the control panel, numbers started appearing and the barrier went down. As he touched the bike, it modified itself and changed from black to red. He rammed through the wall and ended up where the girl was. As he drove off, the guy's and the girl's eyes met and his head started to hurt again. The girl remembers but the guy could not, and as he was driving away quickly, a song started to play, with lyrics like "It hurts to remember you", or maybe "I can't remember you."
>
> The girl was sent on a mission as a driver with a team to clean up a small area. The team wasn't able to do it, though. The infected superpower humans showed up and killed everyone. They were about to kill the girl when she was saved by another guy (say, "Guy #2") who was also infected, but he was not like the others. He also had superpowers and wanted to kill the evil humans.
>
> Guy #2 saved the girl and also got hurt; he was bleeding from a shoulder. I don't remember if he killed the evil guys, or if he just evaded them. They were near a church, so the girl helped him walk and he said, "Let's go inside, we need to hide.", so they went into the church's basement. Guy #2 said that in the corner, there was a pile of broken pieces of wood. If they moved them, they would be able to find an old hose which they could get water from.
>
> The girl asked him how he knew so much about the place. He answered that he grew up in the church, as he was an orphan. This started a flashback for Guy #2:
>
> > As an orphan, he lived there with many children, and there was an old priest who took care of the children. Guy #2 helped in the church's chores and cleaned the church. He wore a big thick black belt on his stomach before he went to the town with the priest to collect charity.
> >
> > The first house they arrived at was that of a rich woman. When she came to the door, the priest asked if she would be kind enough to give charity 
> >     for the orphans in the church. The woman told him that they had already asked last week, before her son came out and said that they should give "the Father" some money and they should have some tea. The woman remarked that her son had a heart of gold, and invited the priest inside.
> >
> > The boy said that he wanted to play a game with Guy #2, which consisted of taking him to a back alley and removing his belt before beating him ( because he was an orphan) and telling him that he should die since no one loved him. A fat man pulling a wooden cart of bakery goods was passing by when he saw this. He yelled at the kids to stop it, and the kids ran away. The fat man came closer and Guy #2 started to cry. He said, "Please don't beat me, too. The kids have beaten me up so much that I can't bear any more." The fat man said he would not beat him and wiped his tears. The fat man then asked where he wanted to go and took him there. He gave Guy #2 some bread as a gift, and even though he was very happy, he didn't eat it, but took it to the orphanage for the kids instead.
> >
> > A few days later, the fat man met him again and gave Guy #2 some more bread and he left happily. Then the fat man was pulling his cart and crossing a stone bridge over water. Suddenly, someone started to push his cart from the side to the edge of the bridge and he started pushing from the other side to stop himself and his cart from falling.
> >
> > The ones who were pushing the cart were the blonde son and his friends, because he had saved Guy #2 from getting beat up and they were taking revenge on him. The fat man and his cart went over the edge. As Guy #2 came back to thank him, he saw what had happened. Seeing the badly injured fat man, Guy #2 said that he knew who had done it, and he named the blonde kid and his friends. They were very rich and trusted, so a crime like this could not be put on them without any evidence.
> >
> > They asked the fat man what happened and who did it. He replies that he did not see who did it, as he was pushing from one side and they from the other. So, they told Guy #2 that he would have to swear on the Bible and say that the the blonde kid and his friends did it, and he agreed. Later, the blonde kid came to Guy #2 and asked him to tell everyone and swear on the Bible that it was him who pushed the fat man over the bridge, because the kid's family gave the church money the most, and if he didn't say it, they would stop giving money to the church and the orphan kids would all die of hunger.
> >
> > This made Guy #2 very sad and depressed. He then took the blame on himself and said he did it because he wanted to steal the bread he had.  Some time later, he found out that his older sister, who was an doctor or something, was attacked by the town's people while returning home. They beat her up so bad that she was covered in blood, and left her in the middle of the road.
>
> That's all he said about his backstory, and they both slept in the church's basement. After waking up, there was a loud noise outside, so they went out to take a look, and there was a large robot coming towards them. The hatch opened and it was the person in charge of the facility, along with a scientist who was Guy #2's sister, who was somehow still alive.

Does anyone know what this anime is?

Comment: People are more likely to read your question if you format it better. For example, you might want to consider using paragraphs.

Comment: Do you remember if the robots were animated with fairly high quality CGI? Also, around what time did you watch it?

Comment: maby the year was around 2011-14 i think bu i cant remember the date  and this is my first time asking a question on line thank you for helping me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on some of the details provided I would guess this is **[Blassreiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blassreiter)**. (Check here for the episode-by-episode synopses: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Blassreiter_episodes)

- It basically has "robot zombies", Demoniacs
- The facility you describe which wants to fight the robot zombies and XAT in Blassreiter seem similar.
- The main character in Blassreiter is one of the few Blassreiter-empowered humans to fight against the Demoniacs rather than with them.
- There is a character who was orphaned and is considered an "Outsider" by society and there are a few episodes centered on a church outside of town.
- Humans who have Blassreiter powers have a "Blassreiter form" which is essentially a mecha shape.

Synopsis:

> The story is set in a fictional Germany and centers around the outbreak of biomechanical creatures called "Demoniacs", who rise from corpses and attack people savagely. The Demoniacs have the ability to merge with most technology including cars and motorcycles, not only gaining control of them but also enhancing their performance greatly. Against them is a group of people known as XAT, Xenogenesis Assault Team, who police these Demoniacs in an attempt to keep the peace and discover the reasons for the "Demoniac" change. All the while, a number of human-turned-Demoniacs appear. Some use their powers for good, others for evil. One will rise above all other Demoniacs to become known as the "Blassreiter"

I don't personally remember that flashback scene which you described at length, but I watched this in 2008 as it aired so my memory has definitely faded.

Comment: +1: ["(Joseph) spent his childhood in a tightly knit community, helping the priest look after the other orphans' needs, tend to their home and helping people in need."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blassreiter#Joseph_arc) I think the flashback is in episode 13.

Comment: @キルア: Yep. The flashback of Guy #2 (Joseph) is indeed in episode 13, which is the same as the description for the most parts. The rest of the description may come from episode 12 or episode 14.

Comment: thanks i'll download it now and tell you whather this is the one

Comment: thanks all and especially mfoy_
It's Blassreiter  i'm very greatfull than you